# insight into array function in python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I am new to Python. And need some help.

1) I have column in csv file which has 20 unique values in 700 rows including blank. I need to convert this into an array. Please help me with the code

```
My_array = np.array(Data['Cities'])

My_array
```

This returns me result in this format:

```
array(['California', 'New York', nan, 'Manhattan', ........ ,'Chicago', 'Washington', 'Washington'], dtype=object)
```

I want to see all the unique names of the cities in this array.

2) I have 2 columns in a csv file - Arrival and Destination. Using Python i need to find the most frequent trips combination. I am not sure which function to use.

Comment: What is `Data`?  Looks like it might be a `pandas` DataFrame created with a `read_csv`.  If so, add a `pandas` tag.  I suspect for this a pandas solution will be better than a numpy one.

Comment: thanks @hpaulj.. Added a tag. Hopefully should find a solution. The data is about people visiting different locations. there are 20 odd cities in the data and i need the output in an array.